# iOS 4.3 Beta 2 Build Issue - Device Only

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I just installed the 4.3 Beta 2 and now I can't build on my device (works fine on the simulator).  My build settings are:

**Base SDK:**        Latest iOS (iOS 4.3)

**Architectures:**   Standard (armv6 armv7)

I am getting the below errors.  What am I missing?

**Error #1**

Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_UIProgressView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PDColoredProgressView in PDColoredProgressView.o

....

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

**Error #2**

in /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.o, file is universal but does not contain a(n) armv7 slice for architecture armv7
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considering that iOS 4.3 is under NDA, as all betas are, you won't find much help here. And anyone who actually does offer you up an answer that could remotely help you, would be breaching their NDA and could be thrown out of the program. My suggestion is to take this to the apple developer forums, there's a private confidential information forum you can use there  (it's in red).

Comment: Thanks,  I will post my question on the apple developer forums.

Answer (score 0):

What is the OS version on Device? Try setting the deployment target to 4.0

Comment: OS Version is 4.3.  Tried setting the deployment target to 4.0, but still no go.

Comment: check the UIKit framework in your project. is it referenced from iPhoneOS4.3.sdk or from iPhoneOS4.2.sdk folder. If from iPhoneOS4.2.sdk then try to delete it and add again.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the framework and reading it.  Still no go.  To be sure I readded all of my frameworks and now I am also receiving these warnings.

ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreGraphics.framework/CoreGraphics, file was built for unsupported file format which is not the architecture being linked (armv6)

If I deleted the frameworks and readded them from iOS4.3 how can 4.2 still be referenced?  Is there more to removing the reference than deleting the .framework file?